# Проблема с отображением сайта

Tags: html, css

Существует сайт: http://ravlextest.freeoda.com/

Так проблема в `<section class="legko">` , фон обрезался , так как я не обладаю навыками css то прошу помощи здесь , вот сам код проблемного блока

```
<section class="legko" style="background-image: url('/img/men1.jpg');">
```

Вот его стили :

```
.legko {
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Господа специалисты помогите исправить! 
У меня на данный момент так :

[image: Пример1]

А должно быть вот так !

[image: Пример2]

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 position: relative;
}

.vidsochi {
       background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
} 

section .des-block p {
 margin-top: 32px;
 font-size: 1.188em;
}
section {
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 position: relative;
}
section .des-block {
 padding: 100px 50px 100px 50px;
 background: url('../img/bgblock.png');
 color: #fff;
}
section .des-block h2 {
 font-size: 2.313em;
}


.map iframe {
    max-height:400px;
    width:100%;
}

.vid {
       background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}

.ico {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.ico1 img {
 margin-left: 9px;
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.ico2 img {
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-top: 11px;
}
.ico3 img {
 margin-left: 11px;
 margin-top: 12px;
}
.ico4 img {
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-top: 11px;
}
.ico5 img {
 margin-left: 9px;
 margin-top: 8px;
}
.ico6 img {
 margin-left: 9px;
 margin-top: 14px;
}
.ico7 img {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 9px;
}
.ico8 img {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 11px;
}
.ditem {
 margin-top: 15px;
 clear: both;
}
.txt {
 padding-top: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.owl-carousel2 .owl-page, .owl-carousel1 .owl-page {
 display: none !important;
}
.owl-carousel2 .owl-controlls.clickable, .owl-carousel3 .owl-controlls.clickable {
 display: none !important;
}
.form input {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 padding: 13px 4px 13px 15px;
 font-size: 1.188em;
 font-style: italic;
 line-height: 1.2;
 color: #234c8c;
 border: 1px solid #264f8f;
}
.form form input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#234c8c;}
.form form input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {color:#234c8c;}
.form form input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {color:#234c8c;}

section h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2em;
 line-height: 1.2;
 color: #234c8c;
}

.form {
 text-align: center;
}

.form button {
 background-color: #27bdbe;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 font-size: 1.188em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 1.2;
 padding: 13px 70px 13px 70px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.frm {
 padding: 10px 0 25px;
 position: relative;
}
.bgf {
 position: relative;
}
.kol1 {
 background: url('../img/kol1.png') no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 12px;
width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 514px;
 height: 253px;
}
.kol2 {
 background: url('../img/kol2.png') no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 top: -19px;
 width: 514px;
 height: 253px;
}

.mesto {
       background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}

.hochu button {
 padding: 13px;
}

.komfort {
       background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}

.prosmotr button {
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #27bdbe;
 box-shadow: none;
 border: 1px solid #27bdbe;
}

.legko {
   
       background-position: 50% 100%;
height: 100%;
   background-size:100%;
    background-attachment:;

}
.owl-buttons {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60px;
 right: 417px;
 width: 30px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #939598;
 border-color: rgb(147, 149, 152);
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #1d9092, #27bdbe);
}
.owl-prev {
     position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    background: url('/img/arrowl.png') no-repeat !important;
    width: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 6px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.owl-next {
   position: absolute;
    right: -16px;
    top: -1px; 
    background: url('/img/arrowr.png') no-repeat !important;
    width: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 6px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.ploshad {
 background: url('/img/bg5-1.jpg'), url('/img/bg5-2.jpg'), url('/img/bg5-3.jpg');
 position: relative;
 background-position: left top, center top, right top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 25% 100%, 50% 100%, 25% 100%;
}
.top_pr {
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;

}

.des-prugl {
 background: url('../img/pramugl.png') no-repeat top center;
padding: 10px 0 325px 0;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.188em;
    max-width: 360px;
    position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 218px;
}
.body_pr {
 padding: 15px 50px 0 50px;
}
.top_pr .numb {
font-size: 2.313em;
}
.top_pr .dom {
 padding-left: 12px;
}
.pdr0 {
   padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.pdl0 {
padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.dc {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 20px;
 background: url('../img/flag1.png') no-repeat;
 width: 116px;
 height: 132px;
 background-size: 70px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-right: 46px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}
.dc2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 20px;
 background: url('../img/flag2.png') no-repeat;
 width: 116px;
 height: 132px;
 background-size: 70px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-right: 46px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}
.dc3 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 560px;
 background: url('../img/flag1.png') no-repeat;
 width: 116px;
 height: 132px;
 background-size: 70px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-right: 46px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}
.item span {
 font-size: 20px;
}
.item p {
 font-size: 12px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .des-block {
        padding: 15px !important; 
    }
     .des-block h2 {
      text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5em !important; 
    }
    .owl-carousel3 {
    }
.pdr0 {
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 468px) {
 .kol1 {
  display: none;
 }
 .des-prugl {
      font-size: 12px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     right: 0;
 }
.des-block {
 padding-bottom: 35px !important;
  }
  .pdl0 {
       padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  .pdm {
   padding: 0px !important;
  }

}

>!
```

```html
<section class="legko" style="background-image: url('/img/men1.jpg');">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="pdm col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-5 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
    <div class="des-block">
    <h2>С нами легко</h2>
       <div class="ditem">
      <div class="ico ico7"><img src="img/ico11.png"></div>
      <div class="txt"><b>Мы пригласим Вас на просмотр</b> и компенсируем Ваши расходы на дорогу и проживание в случае, если Вы решите остановить свой выбор на наших пентхаусах.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="ditem">
      <div class="ico ico8"><img src="img/ico12.png"></div>
      <div class="txt"><b>Полный пакет документов и разрешений,</b> статус квартиры, регистрация сделки в Роскомимуществе и конечно же ключи от Вашей новой квартиры сразу после заключения сделки - именно это делает наше предложение уникальным на рынке недвижимости Сочи.</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/common.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script> 

</body></html>
```

Comment: Не надо добавлять кучу кода или разметки. Уберите из вопроса все лишнее - и скажите в чем вообще проблема.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov там же написано , что у него так (приведён скрин) а надо так (и тоже приведён скрин) и даже дан код проблемного  блока , .

Answer (score 2):

тебе нужно добавить свойство `background-size: cover;`

пример [ссылка на песочницу](http://codepen.io/gessdead/pen/xOgOWO)

именно в твоем css нужно исправить на такое

```
.legko {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

но я бы советовал фоновую картинку тоже задавать в css

```
.legko {
    background-image: url('/img/men1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

тогда в html будет только

```
<section class="legko">
```

*если фоновая картинка не отображается, проверь путь до картинки

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```css
.legko {
    background-image: url('/img/men1.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
```